# TableColumn stop EditCommit if field-input is blank

Tags: java, javafx

I have this `TableColumn<Foo, String> colValue = new TableColumn<>("Value");`

With this settings:

```
colValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));
colValue.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
colValue.setOnEditCommit(event -> {

    //get new value
    String newValue = event.getNewValue().trim();

    //if is empty not update
    if(newValue.isEmpty()){ return; }

    //set new value
    event.getRowValue().setValue(newValue);

    //refresh table
    tableView.refresh();

});
```

What I want is to update the object field directly from table. When double click in cell, change value and commit it.
But I want to not update the value when the field-input is blank.

The above code works fine. It updates the object only if the value is not empty.

But the problem is, if the field-input is black, and there is committed, the object is not updated, but the cell is blank.

How to prevent commit even for cell? I want to see the old value(the real value from object) in cell, if the field-input is blank when commit.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and whatever you do, __do not__ use table.refresh (it's emergency api for rare corner cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by the time the event is fired, it's too late to intercept updating the cell's text.

This is a little bit of a hack (probably the better approach is to subclass `TableCell` directly and implement the behavior to directly call `cancelEdit` when the user hits enter, etc, with an empty string). However, you can override the `commitEdit(...)` method as follows:

```
colValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));
//colValue.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
//colValue.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
//
//    //get new value
//    String newValue = event.getNewValue().trim();
//
//    //if is empty not update
//    if(newValue.isEmpty()){ return; }
//
//    //set new value
//    event.getRowValue().setValue(newValue);
//
//    //refresh table
//    tableView.refresh();
//
//});

colValue.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER) {
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
        if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
            cancelEdit();
        } else {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: _it's too late to intercept updating the cell's text_ is another way to describe the bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187314 :) There's a missing/incorrect internal update in commitEdit that assumes the edited value is accepted.